# Extract xmlns in XML created by xerces

Tags: c++, xml, dom, xerces, xerces-c

I am trying to create a XML using xerces C++. However I am getting  `xmlns=""` after each element node. Can someone please guide me how can this be removed?

Please find my implementation below

```
p_DOMImplementation = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(XMLString::transcode("core"));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved. Issue was coming because I assigned a namespace to Child node but haven't assigned any namespace to root root.

Once I did assigned namespace to root node too the empty xmlns attributes were gone.